# Hadoop in windows : file not found exception

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using hadoop in windows and i've configured everything good (installing cygwin, passwordless ssh etc..)

I've compiled the wordcount program in WC.jar and tried to run. Its running perfectly in standalone mode.. but in fully distributed mode it gives `FileNotFoundException`

Please look into the logs and tel me what is wrong with it. 
i've started the dfs and mapreduce in the MACH1. (thats my master)

```
$ bin/hadoop jar WC.jar WordCount words result

10/07/24 16:57:38 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
10/07/24 16:57:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201007241657_0001
10/07/24 16:57:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
10/07/24 16:57:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_m_0
00003_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-328510/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_m_000003_0/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:57:55 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_r_0
00002_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-328510/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_r_000002_0/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_m_0
00003_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_m_000003_1/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_m_0
00003_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_m_000003_2/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_m_0
00002_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_m_000002_0/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_r_0
00001_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_r_000001_0/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_m_0
00002_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-328510/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_m_000002_1/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201007241657_0001_m_0
00002_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-328510/mapred/local/taskTracke
r/jobcache/job_201007241657_0001/attempt_201007241657_0001_m_000002_2/work/tmp d
oes not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSys
tem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.
java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)

10/07/24 16:58:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201007241657_0001
10/07/24 16:58:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0

328510@01HW179531 /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.2
$`
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code where you call `DistributedCache.addCacheFile`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219012/filenotfoundexception-when-using-hadoop-distributed-cache) for a possible answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have seen this exception before but I don't have access to my old logs to confirm it. I solved my FileNotFoundException by **reformatting the namenode**. You might want to check the namenode logs for "inconsistent state" to confirm the cause before reformatting.

Comment: hi @wei, me too having the same issue, i tried the reformatting too but still the problem exist

Comment: Did you see "inconsistent state" in the log?