# FileNotFound Exception when trying to store file in hadoop distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, distributed-cache

I try to store a local file on the distributed cache.
The file exists, but I get a File not found exception

code fragment:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("file://"+fileName), conf);   
RunningJob job = JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

Exception:

```
Error initializing attempt_201310150245_0066_m_000021_0:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /Workflow/data does not exist
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:468)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:380)
     at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TaskDistributedCacheManager.setupCache(TaskDistributedCacheManager.java:180)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1454)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1445)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1360)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2786)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the file really in `/Workflow/data` or is it in `/somepath/Workflow/data`?

Comment: It's likely that the URI needs to be a hdfs one?

Comment: @Ophir, I am facing same problem. I have confirmed that file is present in HDFS but still getting this problem. How did you solved your problem?

Comment: @Shekhar I used a work around - it was a small configuration file, so I copied the parameters to the job configuration

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is put your file in the HDFS, while hadoop is running. You can do that with

`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal <localPath> <HDFSPath>`

I don' think that you need the "file://" prefix.
Try something like that:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/hduser/stopwords/stopwords.txt"), conf);
```

being sure that this path exists in the HDFS, not in your local file system.

For example, you can run the command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/stopwords
```

to be sure that this path exists.

More commands can be found in [shell commands for hadoop 1.2.1](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/file_system_shell.html)

Comment: I prefer a solution that doesn't involve copying to hdfs

Comment: Does this method help? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html#setLocalFiles%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the URI like this:

```
new File(<path_to_file>).toURI()
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219012/filenotfoundexception-when-using-hadoop-distributed-cache).